# customizing the font color in intellijIDEA in the "run" code section

Tags: java, intellij-idea

in the intellijIDEA you run the code you write.

but is there any way to customize the color of the font the "run" section in the intellijIDEA?

Answer (score 1):

Open Settings (Strg+Alt+S), on the left select Editor -> Color Scheme -> Console Colors
[image: here you can see a picture of these settings]

here you can change the colour of your font in the run section (console), log console and terminal